# How to perform string substitution to construct a json string in zsh?

Tags: zsh

This is my function

```
function print_doc_json() {
    docId=$1
    echo '{ ":d": { "S": "$(docId)" }}'
}
```

I want the output of  `print_doc_json abc123`  to be `{ ":d": { "S": "abc123" }}`

However it came out as `{ ":d": { "S": "$(docId)" }}`. The `DocId` is not substituted.

How can I get a string substitution in  string already enclosed in a pair of quote?

Comment: If you have `jq` available (and I recommend using it), use `jq -n --arg d "$docId" '{":d": {S: $d}}'` instead of `echo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes. First, variable substitution is done like this: `${docId}`, not like this: `$(docId)`

Second, if you enclose a string in single quotes (`'`), no variable substitution is performed inside - you have to use double quotes (`"`). Be aware that in this case you must escape the double quotes that you want printed:

```
function print_doc_json() {
    docId=$1
    echo "{ \":d\": { \"S\": \"${docId}\" }}"
}
```

Alternatively you can use single quotes outside, but then you must also do the substitution outside:

```
function print_doc_json() {
    docId=$1
    echo '{ ":d": { "S": "'${docId}'" }}'
}
```

This is three concatenated strings: `'{ ":d": { "S": "'`, `${docId}` and `'" }}'`.

Comment: This is fragile, assuming that `docId` doesn't contain any whitespace, double quotes, or other characters in need of escaping.